# CMake errors: not find VTK files

Tags: cmake, vtk

I am using OpenCV and PCL. Recently, I have been trying to implement a demo, but the program cannot be compiled correctly. The following is my `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(point_cloud_join)

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -O3" )

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories("/usr/include/eigen3/")
include_directories("/usr/include/pcl-1.8")


find_package(PCL REQUIRED QUIET
 COMPONENT common io
 )

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
# message(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(joinMap joinMap.cpp)

target_link_libraries(joinMap ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

And I always got these errors:

```
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled

-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMPONENT
-- Could NOT find PCL_COMPONENT (missing: PCL_COMPONENT_LIBRARY PCL_COMPONENT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

cmake said it cannot find `libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so` and `vtk`, yet I do find the two files but not in the exact same name--`libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `vtk6`.
Now I am not sure what to do. Should I reinstall VTK or what ?

Comment: "Should I reinstall VTK" - Probably, yes. At least, suggested variant "An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully." tells about broken installation. Also note to the file `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake`: it should be (re-)installed alongside with VTK package.

Comment: Can I just copy the two files and rename them as the CMake asked for ?

Comment: "Can I just copy the two files and rename them as the CMake asked for?" - No, it is better to not manually rename or move files which should be installed. Manual intervention into these files could lead to subtle, hard-to-debug bugs in your current or future projects.

Comment: If you want to list components of PCL to find, the correct argument for which to list components is `COMPONENTS`, not `COMPONENT`: `find_package(PCL REQUIRED QUIET COMPONENTS common io)`

Comment: Right, thanks. I commented the component line though.

Comment: I made a hard link between them and the problem solved, which may seem dangerous.